# When using Shadowbox, how to keep the "loading ..." div displaying until the page is fully loaded?

Tags: loading, shadowbox

I'm using shadowbox to open a page when a link is clicked and it does open the page when the link is clicked.

The problem is that "Loading ..." icon appears for 1 second then disappears whereas my page takes about 5 seconds to load.

How to keep the "loading ..." div displaying until the page is fully loaded and ready?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Shadowbox.init({                
            onFinish: shadowboxFinish               
        });
```

then

```
function shadowboxFinish() {

            $("#sb-loading").show();

            $("#sb-player").load(function () {

                $("#sb-loading").hide();
             });               
        }
```